# PQconnectdb set search_path (schema) while connecting

Tags: postgresql, libpq

How do I specify the `search_path` while connecting to my postgres db using [`PQconnectdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-connect.html)? I want to set the `search_path` to `my_schema`. I'm currently using the following connection command:

```
PQconnectdb("host=localhost user=my_user password=my_password port=5432 dbname=my_db")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the following to your connection info:

```
options='-csearch_path=my_schema'
```

So, it would become:

```
PQconnectdb("host=localhost user=my_user password=my_password port=5432 dbname=my_db options='-csearch_path=my_schema'")
```

**Reference:**

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D960CB61B694CF459DCFB4B0128514C20886AD46@exadv11.host.magwien.gv.at